# function multi-downloading for array of files

Tags: javascript, html

It is necessary to make a function that the file loader is called from the code.
That is, a list of paths is passed and the browser starts downloading them. Example 1:
downloadFiles([
"/1.jpg",
"/2.jpg",
"/3.jpg"
])

the function itself is in the outline (though only for one file)

```
function donwloadFiles(url, sourceElement) {
    disableOnUnloadPage = true;
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = url;

    if (sourceElement) {
        a.target = sourceElement.target;
    }

    dojo.body().appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    disableOnUnloadPage = false;
}
```

If you run several files at once like this, they are not downloaded.
The browser has some internal logic that does not allow this to be done.

How to remove SourceElement and make it accept an array of links as in example 1.

Comment: why don’t you pass an array of files as an array literal? however, it’s most common to pass a multi-file-request to the webserver which in turn packs all requested files into a zip archive and offers that one for download

Comment: there is a working multi-download function https://github.com/sindresorhus/multi-download . I want to make a similar functionality with my own, but I don't have enough experience

Comment: there is a way to load the files via the fetch api afaik

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Browsers do not let webpages spawn multiple windows or downloads.

It would be too abusable.

Comment: this is not entirely true. after some windows, the user gets asked whether he wants to allow the spawning of more windows in most common browsers

Comment: can run these downloads at a certain interval